# Why does A resolve true, but B does not?

Tags: python-2.7

Why does A resolve true, but B does not?

```
Bosses = {
'A' : 5,
'B' : [5,6]
}

for key, value in Bosses.iteritems():
    if value == 5:
        print "Yes for " + key
    else:
        print "No for " + key
```

Comment: Because A equals 5, and B is a list. A list isn't equal to 5.

Comment: Because [5,6] isn't equal to 5.

Comment: Can I make it resolve the list to integers so it will resolve? Else is there a better approach to this type of comparison?

Comment: Well what's the actual comparison you want to make?

Comment: This is just a prototype, but I'm eventually planning to make a list of boss times, and then press a hotkey to check which is the next  boss that will be up for a video game.  Each boss is will be up multiple times per day.

Comment: Bosses = {
'A' : [3:00, 5:00, 7:00],
'B' : [3:15, 5:15, 7:15]
}

Comment: This is my first time here, and you guys voted me -5?  :(  Doesn't make a new user to the site feel very welcomed.

Comment: We are sorry for you to feel unwelcome and I am sure that is not on of the community members their intention, however I must agree to some of their comments. These are Python basics and the post does not really follow the [How do I ask a good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try to dive in the basics a little more before posting a question. If you still can't figure it out, tell us more about what you have tried to actually understand the issue. But you don't need to feel unwelcome, it is due to the system that keeps the community as clean as possible for everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an additional check like this

```
if (isinstance(value, list) and 5 in value) or value == 5:
    print "Yes for " + key
else:
    print "No for " + key
```

Comment: I have got to this point...  and it works if the time is exactly the timeNow, but I'd like to check within a certain time span, say like within the next 15 minutes.  The problem now seems to be that my times are in string values and I need to int so I can do math with them.  I have also tried using time in decimal formats.

Comment: Alternately tried like this:  

Bosses = {
'Evolved Jungle Wurm' : [0.00, 4.00, 8.50, 13.00, 16.00, 21.00],
'Karka Queen' : [2.00, 6.30, 11.00, 14.00, 19.00, 22.00],
'Tequatl the Sunless' : [3.00, 7.50, 12.00, 15.00, 20.00, 23.00]
}

Comment: PS: Sorry about the formating in the comments, it doesn't look good.  Maybe I can share it another way, if you are willing to assist.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9GJuga02

Comment: Made some progress on my own:  https://pastebin.com/KgXfvft5

Comment: Better to post a separate question on the new problem you have.

Comment: I Couldn't post another question for 4 more days.  But I got everything figured out once I got past this one hurdle.  Thanks again to Gayan.